# How to set list box value on jsp from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Here. i have created list box on my jsp file and i got the selected value in my servlet by using `getParameter`. now i want to set the value of listbox in the same jsp file which i have previously selected when i reload the same jsp file from servlet.

---

jsp file

```
<tr><td>Operation:<select name="state" >
            <option value="1">Addition</option>
            <option value="2">Subtraction</option>
            <option value="3">Multiplication</option>
            <option value="4">Division</option>
                  </select></td></tr>
```

---

servlet file

```
operation=req.getParameter("state");
    n3=Integer.parseInt(operation);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the select tag attribute `selected`:

```
<select name="state">
    <option value="1" ${'1' eq param.state ? 'selected' : ''}>Addition</option>
    <option value="2" ${'2' eq param.state ? 'selected' : ''}>Subtraction</option>
    <option value="3" ${'3' eq param.state ? 'selected' : ''}>Multiplication</option>
    <option value="4" ${'4' eq param.state ? 'selected' : ''}>Division</option>
</select>
```

Note: make sure you are redirecting to the jsp using `RequestDispatcher.forward(request, response)`

${} is Expression Language(EL) provided in jsp. In EL, `${param.state}` is equivalent to `request.getParameter("state")`

`eq` is logical operator in EL, you can even use `==` for the same.

To use with request attributes, you may try:

```
<option value="1" ${'1' eq requestScope.data ? 'selected' : ''}>Addition</option>
```

Comment: **Aravind:** can you explain it?... '${'1' eq param.state ? 'selected' : ''}' here what is eq param.state?

Comment: '<option value="1" ${'1' eq request.getAttribute("data") ? 'selected' : ''}>Addition</option>'  i have used like this.. but it throws error.

Comment: @user3075386, why are you using attribute? Aren't you rediecting using `RequestDispatcher.forward(request, response)` ?

Comment: @aravind, i have used this coding on my servlet `req.setAttribute("data",n3);RequestDispatcher.forward(request,response)`.

Comment: @user3075386, you don't need that attribute, as you are already sending the same request object to the jsp. Hence the parameter `state` can be still available in the jsp. Did you tried my answer without alterations?

Comment: Even if i use your code it display an error like this `The function state must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified`

Comment: i tried your code also without changing anything.. but it shows the same error which i have mentioned previously.

Comment: @user3075386, can you try `[${param}]` and `[${param.state}]` printing on jsp? Let me know what it shows?

Comment: @user3075386, also try this `[${requestScope.data}]` if you want to stick to attribute